# Spring boot batch - Running multiple batch jobs from schedule tasks causing concurrency issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have created three different batch jobs using spring boot + batch. When i try to run these jobs via scheduled tasks. At same time (with few seconds difference). I run into unexpected issues in Filereader as its start reporting parsing exceptions. This works fine if is run these jobs in order or via CommandLineRunner (which run one job at a time). Each reader component is configured at Step scope. Can someone please take a look and suggest a possible fix ? Code below.

```
Job 1 :

        @Bean(JOB_NAME)
        public Job importMonetryFilesJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get(JOB_NAME).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener).flow(step1())
                    .end().build();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Bean(STEP_1)
        public Step step1() {
            TaskletStep step1 = stepBuilderFactory.get(STEP_1).<RawMonteryFileInput, RawMonteryFileInput>chunk(1)
                    .reader(reader()).processor(processor()).writer(writer()).faultTolerant()
                    .skipPolicy(new JobSkipPolicy()).listener(monetryCustomSkipListener()).build();
            step1.registerStepExecutionListener(batchSweepStepContext());
            return step1;
        }

        @Bean(READER_NAME)
        @StepScope
        public MultiResourceItemReader<RawMonteryFileInput> reader() {

            MultiResourceItemReader<RawMonteryFileInput> multiReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<RawMonteryFileInput>();

            multiReader.setResources(inputFiles);
            multiReader.setDelegate(readerInternal());
            return multiReader;
        }

        @Bean(READER_NAME + "_internal")
        @StepScope
        public FlatFileItemReader<RawMonteryFileInput> readerInternal() {
            CustomFlatFileItemReader<RawMonteryFileInput> reader = new CustomFlatFileItemReader<>();
            reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new MergingItemSeparator());
            reader.setLineMapper(sourceAwareLineMapper());
            reader.setFileLocation(processedFilesLocation);
            return reader;
        }

        @Bean(PROCESSOR_NAME)
        @StepScope
        public ValidatingItemProcessor<RawMonteryFileInput> processor() {
            SpringValidator<RawMonteryFileInput> springValidator = new SpringValidator<RawMonteryFileInput>();
            springValidator.setValidator(validator);
            return new ValidatingItemProcessor<RawMonteryFileInput>(springValidator);
        }

        @Bean(WRITER_NAME)
        @StepScope
        public FlatFileItemWriter<RawMonteryFileInput> writer() {

            FlatFileItemWriter<RawMonteryFileInput> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<RawMonteryFileInput>();
            writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(getWriterFileName()));
            writer.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);
            writer.setLineAggregator(new CustomDelimitedLineAggregator<RawMonteryFileInput>() {
                {
                    setDelimiter("|");
                    setFieldExtractor(new CustomBeanWrapperExtractor<RawMonteryFileInput>() {
                        {
                            setNames(MonetryJobConstants.WRITER_HEADER);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return writer;
        }

    Job 2 :

        @Bean(JOB_NAME)
        public Job importAccountBalanceJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener) {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get(JOB_NAME).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).listener(listener).flow(step1())
                    .end().build();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Bean(STEP_1)
        public Step step1() {
            TaskletStep step1 = stepBuilderFactory.get(STEP_1).<AccountBalanceFileInput, AccountBalanceFileInput>chunk(1)
                    .reader(reader()).processor(processor()).writer(writer()).faultTolerant()
                    .skipPolicy(new JobSkipPolicy()).listener(accountBalanceCustomSkipListener()).build();
            step1.registerStepExecutionListener(batchSweepStepContext());
            return step1;
        }

        @Bean(READER_NAME)
        @StepScope
        public MultiResourceItemReader<AccountBalanceFileInput> reader() {

            // Assert.notEmpty(inputFiles, "Input files on location are required.");
            MultiResourceItemReader<AccountBalanceFileInput> multiReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<AccountBalanceFileInput>();

            multiReader.setResources(inputFiles);
            multiReader.setDelegate(readerInternal());
            return multiReader;
        }

        @Bean(READER_NAME + "_internal")
        @StepScope
        public FlatFileItemReader<AccountBalanceFileInput> readerInternal() {
            CustomFlatFileItemReader<AccountBalanceFileInput> reader = new CustomFlatFileItemReader<>();
            reader.setRecordSeparatorPolicy(new MergingItemSeparator());
            reader.setLineMapper(sourceAwareLineMapper());
            reader.setFileLocation(processedFilesLocation);
            return reader;
        }

        @Bean(PROCESSOR_NAME)
        @StepScope
        public ValidatingItemProcessor<AccountBalanceFileInput> processor() {
            SpringValidator<AccountBalanceFileInput> springValidator = new SpringValidator<AccountBalanceFileInput>();
            springValidator.setValidator(validator);
            return new ValidatingItemProcessor<AccountBalanceFileInput>(springValidator);
        }

        @Bean(WRITER_NAME)
        @StepScope
        public FlatFileItemWriter<AccountBalanceFileInput> writer() {

            FlatFileItemWriter<AccountBalanceFileInput> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<AccountBalanceFileInput>();
            writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(getWriterFileName()));
            writer.setShouldDeleteIfEmpty(true);
            writer.setLineAggregator(new CustomDelimitedLineAggregator<AccountBalanceFileInput>() {
                {
                    setDelimiter("|");
                    setFieldExtractor(new CustomBeanWrapperExtractor<AccountBalanceFileInput>() {
                        {
                            setNames(AccountBalanceJobConstants.WRITER_HEADER);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return writer;
        }

    Config : 

        @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableBatchProcessing(modular = true)
    public class BatchJobsConfig {

        @Bean
        public ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
        }

        @Bean
        public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager)
                throws Exception {
            MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager);
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            return factory;
        }

        @Bean
        public JobRepository jobRepository(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean repositoryFactory) throws Exception {
            return repositoryFactory.getObject();
        }

        @Bean
        public JobExplorer jobExplorer(MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean repositoryFactory) {
            return new SimpleJobExplorer(repositoryFactory.getJobInstanceDao(), repositoryFactory.getJobExecutionDao(),
                    repositoryFactory.getStepExecutionDao(), repositoryFactory.getExecutionContextDao());
        }

        @Bean
        public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
            SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
            launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
            return launcher;
        }

    Schedule task looks like this :

        @Slf4j
    @Component
    @EnableScheduling
    public class AccountBalanceJobSchedular {

        @Autowired
        private SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(AccountBalanceFileLoadJob.JOB_ACCOUNT_BAL_LOAD)
        private Job batchJob;


        @Scheduled(cron = "*/6 * * * * *")
        public  void perform() throws Exception {


            JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.nanoTime() + UUID.randomUUID().toString())).toJobParameters();

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(batchJob, param);

            log.info("Job finished with status :" + execution.getStatus());
        }
    }
```

Each job has its own name and its own class file so each bean name varies according to job name.This works fine if jobs are not running simultaneously. Any help will be much appreciated.

I am using Spring Boot 2, Spring Batch 4 and Java 10.

Comment: org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult is being thrown. I think my BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper is not threadsafe as i have added custom binding in init binding method. Any idea ?

Comment: One thing confirmed so far is that, whole issue is happening because date formatter is not thread safe. I changed the date fields to string and changed the binding as well. Files were then processed with out any issue. Now i need to look for the ways to thread safe date conversion for my date fields.

Comment: Are you running all jobs in the same JVM?

Comment: Yes, they are running on same VM.

Comment: The `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` is not designed for multi-threading (See its Javadoc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html). I would recommend using the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` either with a real database or an embedded database.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, I will setup the in memory database, as i need to use this application with Amazon Redshift, so spring batch metadata tables fails at sequence creation and Blob inserts which are required and Redshift doesn't support it. But right now the issue is due to Date conversion. I need to figure out how to do  thread safe conversion/formatting for both read and write. For now i have resolved the issue by using LocalDate and LocalDateTime formatting, but solution is simply not up to the mark and clean, as i am using initbinder to register property editors.